# menuNode.isExtensible is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs

For the expanding the tree structure, I'm using **Node.isExpanded()**. If I double clicks the tree, the duplicate child is getting creating.

So because of this duplicate error I'm using the

```
Node.isExtensible()
```

Its working fine with the tree structure without creating the duplicate. But I'm getting the below error because of the above method.

**Uncaught TypeError: menuNode.isExtensible is not a function**

Can anyone suggest me to remove the error or else provide me the suggestion for this. I'm using **Extjs** version 6. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you find that function? It does not exist if you believe the official sencha docs.

Comment: Hi @Alexander. this function is there in the sencha docs. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Object.html#static-method-isExtensible. and Node.isExpanded() is also available in the docs. Please view and provide me the suggestion.

Comment: `Object.isExtensible` is marked as static, so you would use `Object.isExtensible(menuNode)`. However, this has nothing to do with your problem, because the function is about a javascript/ES5 language feature, not about ExtJS nodes. The duplicate entry is not created right now because the error stops your program from working. Once the error is fixed, the duplicate entry is being created again.

Comment: That said, this is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd say try again, ask about your problem...